# Coldfusion WSDL IllegalArgumentException on cfinvokeargument

Tags: web-services, coldfusion, wsdl, cfinvoke

When you are calling a method of a webservice and want to omit an unrequired numeric variable that has a default value set coldfusion will throw the following error:

```
The fault returned when invoking the web service operation is:<br>
<pre>'' java.lang.IllegalArgumentException</pre>
```

Example:

```
<cfinvoke
    webservice = "http://*.cfc?WSDL" 
    method="getFriendlyDay" 
    returnvariable="response"
    refreshWSDL="true"
>
        <cfinvokeargument name="dayNumber" omit="true"/>
</cfinvoke>
```

webservice component:

```
<cffunction name="getFriendlyDay" access="remote" returntype="any" output="no" description="get a friendly date from a number">   

        <cfargument name="dayNumber" type="numeric" required="no" default="0">
        ...
</cffunction>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution to this is to just not omit the argument. Pass in the default value. I just wanted to record this in case someone else gets the same error. Thus far it has only occurred on numeric values.

```
<cfinvoke
    webservice = "http://*.cfc?WSDL" 
    method="getFriendlyDay" 
    returnvariable="response"
    refreshWSDL="true"
>
        <cfinvokeargument name="dayNumber" value="0" >
</cfinvoke>
```

**Update:**

I believe this probably relates to [the bug outlined here](http://www.jalpino.com/index.cfm/event/read/entry/Issues_when_calling_a_Coldfusion_web_services_with_optional_arguments):

> The way Coldfusion handles optional arguments as a remote service is
>   that it allows the calling client to pass in a null value. In a
>   document/literal or rpc/encoded WSDL description, an element can
>   accept null unless it specifies "nillable='false'". The generated
>   WSDLs from Coldfusion do not use "nillable='false'" or "minOccurs='0'"
>   which instructs the client that they must include the parameter and
>   that it is ok to pass in a null value.
>
> The problem however is that "numeric" or "boolean" argument types that
>   are optional will throw an "Illegal Argument Exception" when being
>   called by a client who is trying to explicitly pass in null ...

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens when you specify both ie `<cfinvokeargument name="dayNumber" omit="true" value="0" />`? Reason for asking is [the docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7e09.html) say *It is an error to specify omit="yes" if the cfinvokewebservice attribute is not specified.* I am hoping the actual behavior is not as silly as it sounds ...

Comment: I tried both ways :) I assumed that cfinvokewebservice attribute referred to the name.

Comment: Yep, sounds like that is the issue. (I agree with the author. Requiring that you specify an *optional* attribute really is counter intuitive...)