# SOAP web service with optional arguments

Tags: web-services, soap, coldfusion, wsdl, coldfusion-11

I have created a SOAP service which has some optional method arguments.
I have found some issues:

1. While calling the web service I always need to pass all the arguments irrespective of whether they are optional or not.
2. I found that in ColdFusion we can omit the optional arguments by adding `omit=true` in `cfinvokeargument`. But still we need to add `cfinvokeargument` for each argument. It doesn't solve much problem.
3. Since a web service is meant to be accessible from any platform or language, the `omit=true` hack may not be available in other languages.

So my question is, how to deal with the issues. Is there any way to get rid of optional arguments while calling a web service?

Comment: What language/method are you using to access the webservice other than coldfusion?

Comment: It is intended to be used with dot net and php.

Comment: What happened when you tried accessing it from .net and/or php?  Are you sure it applies to *all* optional arguments? Not sure about CF11, but I remember [this CF9 issue](http://www.elliottsprehn.com/cfbugs/bugs/86000) that applied to [optional numeric arguments only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21924722/coldfusion-wsdl-illegalargumentexception-on-cfinvokeargument). Strings, for example, can be omitted.

Comment: @Leigh I haven't tested it on other environments yet. It was a general question. And yes, `omit=true` applies to all optional arguments in CF11.
https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfinvokeargument.

Comment: It would be good to confirm it.  *And yes, omit=true applies to all optional arguments in CF11* The issue was not cfinvokeargument. It was that the wsdl was generated in such a way that it allowed optional arguments of type="string" but not type="numeric".

Comment: Do you have default values for your optional arguments?

Comment: I played around a bit. I created a small cfc with a function with two cfarguments. One mandatory, second optional. I called it from a cfm script with cfinvoke and indeed it only worked when two cfinvokearguments were present. I didn't know that. I then did a test with PHP using the built in SoapClient. This works perfectly when only the mandatory argument is passed in. See my codes: https://gist.github.com/bardware/36385fe3abf870540f61

Comment: I added a Visual Basic sample. It works when only one argument is set.